# systemd service restarting without any obvious cause

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I have two Spring applications that chug along nicely, nothing special happening, and then out of the blue the applications restart; journalctl shows these lines:

```
Jan 15 04:43:11 nyota.softworks.nl systemd[1]: Stopping calendaraggregator.service...
Jan 15 04:43:11 nyota.softworks.nl systemd[1]: calendaraggregator.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 15 04:43:11 nyota.softworks.nl systemd[1]: Stopped calendaraggregator.service.
Jan 15 04:43:11 nyota.softworks.nl systemd[1]: calendaraggregator.service: Consumed 3min 313ms CPU time.
Jan 15 04:43:11 nyota.softworks.nl systemd[1]: Started calendaraggregator.service.
Jan 15 10:41:43 nyota.softworks.nl systemd[1]: Stopping calendaraggregator.service...
Jan 15 10:41:43 nyota.softworks.nl systemd[1]: calendaraggregator.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 15 10:41:43 nyota.softworks.nl systemd[1]: Stopped calendaraggregator.service.
Jan 15 10:41:43 nyota.softworks.nl systemd[1]: calendaraggregator.service: Consumed 1min 48.505s CPU time.
Jan 15 10:41:43 nyota.softworks.nl systemd[1]: Started calendaraggregator.service.
Jan 15 18:17:17 nyota.softworks.nl systemd[1]: Stopping calendaraggregator.service...
Jan 15 18:17:17 nyota.softworks.nl systemd[1]: calendaraggregator.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 15 18:17:17 nyota.softworks.nl systemd[1]: Stopped calendaraggregator.service.
Jan 15 18:17:17 nyota.softworks.nl systemd[1]: calendaraggregator.service: Consumed 2min 24.748s CPU time.
Jan 15 18:17:17 nyota.softworks.nl systemd[1]: Started calendaraggregator.service.
```

But the systemctl configuration AFAIK does not do a restart, not even after failure (took that out to debug this).

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/calendaraggregator/
User=calendaraggregator
Group=calendaraggregator
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/calendaraggregator/run.sh
```

Is there anyway to see what triggered the shutdown?

The log of the application is not of much use, it only says `INFO org.springframework.core.log.CompositeLog [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] Stopping.` without any reason / exception. Also, the application is restarted externally, since the main is called again (I logged that) and AFAIK I do not have systemd configured to restart.

---

Update 2024-02-10

After many tries it seems to be a compound problem. First, SpringBoot has internal restart functionality, either through the actuator or through the developer tools.

https://javapointers.com/spring/spring-boot/how-to-restart-spring-boot-automatically-using-actuator/

The actuator does not do something that quickly, but the development tools have a way of sneaking themselves into the production jar. By build it with the maven shade plugin for example. To prevent development tools from becoming active, make sure to specify the following option when starting java:

`-Dspring.devtools.restart.enabled=false`

But the restarts are still happening after that.

After removing the systemd configuration completely, creating a new start shell script, and only logging the calling of the original start script, the restarts problems are gone. But I can still see the original start shell script being called.

So patched but not solved: what is still calling the original start script?!

Comment: What do the logs of the application say? Spring applications usually have pretty detailed and configurable logging,

Comment: See additional information in the question; the logging is not clear, all it says that it is shutting down.

Comment: Because the issue is irregular, trying stuff takes a lot of time. I'm now taking systemd out of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not formally an answer, but more a work around. The systemd service kept restarting without probable cause, but it turned out that if I moved the service to the user it would no longer.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User#Example